# Obtain all feasible solutions in Python while Gurobi is running

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

Using the [`gurobipy`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/quickstart_mac/py_python_interface.html) Python library for [Gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/) I would like to obtain all feasible models while the solver is running, to store or process them on the fly. I found that [callbacks](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_cb_s.html) seem the best way to do so. However:

1. Is it enough to check `where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL` to obtain *all* feasible solutions, as in the code below? Is it guaranteed that the objective function strictly improves between consecutive `MIPSOL` calls of the callback?
2. If I try to read the value of the variables from inside the callback (line `(b)` below) I get an `AttributeError`, while `cbGetSolution` (line `(a)` below) works fine but forces me to map each value in the returned list to the appropriate variable. Is there a way to make line `(b)` work?

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

model = gp.Model("mymodel")
y = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
x = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
model.update()
model.addConstr(x + 3 * y <= 1000)
model.addConstr(5 * x + y <= 1000)
model.setObjective(x + y, GRB.MAXIMIZE)

def mycallback(model, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        print("Feasible solution:", model.cbGetSolution(model._vars))  # (a) Ok
        print("Feasible solution:", x.x, y.x)  # (b) AttributeError

model._vars = model.getVars()
model.optimize(mycallback)

if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal solution:", x.x, y.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no other way than (a) to query the solution values from within a callback.
In general, only improving solutions should be found as "new solution". To be sure, you could check the objective value against the previous incumbent.

You can also use the [SolFiles](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/solfiles.html) parameter to write new solutions to disk right away.